# getting error when using the dependency in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

when i add dependency to pubspec.yaml files ,in some dependency i get error ,i tried many to resolve it but i can't able to resolve it.

getting this error when using image picker dependency
i tried

1. flutter clean
2. restart the pc
3. reinstall the app

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
```

Comment: Can you mention which version of Flutter and ImagePicker are you using?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8

Comment: image_picker: ^0.6.6+1

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions to what might occur:

- Pay attention to indentation in your pubspec.yaml file.
- Make sure that you don't have any error on dependency version.
- Make sure that you run `flutter pub get` after adding dependency
- Probably it is not documented that you have to add following permission to Android manifest file:

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />`
- Sometimes it might be needed to clean cache and run the project again by using `flutter clean && flutter run` command on terminal.